# URL property for a web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

```
<add key="WebReference.Service" value="http://192.168.0.134:97/Service.asmx"/>
```

This works fine in my local system. Both my application and web service in my local system.
Now i want to use this web service(in my local system) from a hosted web application.In that case what url shold I give as 'value' to the above code.

Answer (score 0):

the Valid Ip of your host should be in value, to get valid IP of host just use ping command

open cmd and ping hostname  like ping www.google.com

Comment: My hosted application is in sub domain (for eg demo.mycompany.com) and the web service is in my local system.

Comment: Ok you should get valid Ip for your local host to make it available on the net,contact with your ISP about it

Comment: I have a  static IP in another system. There is file named Index.html. Then i rooted http://xx.xx.xx.xx/Index.html to http://192.168.0.134:97/Service.asmx. Will it work?

Comment: if  you route all IO packets on port 97 in your porxy server to 192.168.0.134 it should work,I assume you have static IP on a machine that installed proxy server on it ,andt his machine have access to your local LAN